# Convenient way to add lambda functions together?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, python-2.x

Let's say I have this function in a python module:

```
def functionmaker(a,b):
     return lambda x: (a*x) + b
```

Now let's say I am given a list of this format:
`ablist = [[a1, b1], [a2, b2]...[an, bn]]` of arbitrary length.

My goal is to add up all the resulting functions you get from these a's and b's.

Of course, with the simple example I gave of ax+b, you could algebraically work it out to being `(a1 + a2 + ... an)x + (b1  + b2 + ... bn)`. But let's ignore that for a moment. The function I am actually working with is a contracted gaussian molecular orbital function, and it's not as easy to trick your way out of the problem with algebra.

What I wanted to do was something like this:

```
function = lambda x: (a1*x) + b1
q = 2

while q < n:
     function = lambda x: function(x) + (ablist[q][0]*x) + ablist[q][1])
     q += 1
```

But it seems you can't call a function inside itself like that. I was hoping it would just over-write the old version of "function" with the new one, but I guess not. I guess I probably need to do some kind of recursive way, but maybe there is a nicer way?

By the way I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Could you format your code out a little bit, there's a function that's just plain text, and unindented.

Comment: For what it's worth, `lambda` functions _can_ call themselves in their definition.

Comment: What do you mean "add up" the functions? Evaluate them all and add the results? Or generate a series of nested functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your question, you could use the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function and pass it a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) argument to accomplish the goal:

```
def functionmaker(a, b):
     return lambda x: (a*x) + b

ablist = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
x = 1
total = sum(functionmaker(a, b)(x) for a, b in ablist)
print(total)  # -> 21
```

If you need to compute this quantity for many different values of `x`, then it might be worthwhile to optimize things for doing that:

```
functions = [functionmaker(a, b) for a, b in ablist]
sum_of_functions = lambda x: sum(function(x) for function in functions)

for x in (1, 1.5, 2):
    print('sum_of_functions(x={:.1f}) -> {:.1f}'.format(x, sum_of_functions(x)))
```

Output:

```
sum_of_functions(x=1.0) -> 21.0
sum_of_functions(x=1.5) -> 25.5
sum_of_functions(x=2.0) -> 30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> def functionmaker(a, b):
...     return lambda x: a*x + b
...
>>> def summer_funcs(args):
...     return lambda x: sum(functionmaker(*a)(x) for a in args)
...
>>> arguments = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> summer_funcs(arguments)(1)
21
```

Or if you prefer:

```
>>> f = summer_funcs(arguments)
>>> f(1)
21
>>> f(2)
30
```